# How to get a range of <p> tags from a <div> with Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

There is a `<div>` on a site with class "entrytext".
This returns 75 `<p>` tags:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
Elements p = doc.select("div[class=entrytext] > p");
```

What I want is the following:
The first `<p>` looks like this:

```
<font>SBS</font>
```

Twelve `<p>` tags later, there is this:

```
<font>KBS2</font>
```

How can I return all `<p>` tags between `<font>SBS</font>` and  `<font>KBS2</font>`?

EDIT:

```
<p><font color="#ff0000" size="6">SBS</font></p>

<p><img src="http://www.koreandrama.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Six-Flying-Dragons-04-105x150.jpg" alt="Six Flying Dragons 04" width="105" height="150" class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-46033"> </p>
<p><a href="http://www.koreandrama.org/six-flying-dragons/" target="_blank">육룡이 나르샤 / Six Flying Dragons / 六龍飛天</a><br> Broadcast period: 2015-Oct-05 to 2016-March-22<br> Air time: Monday &amp; Tuesday 22:00</p>

repeats another 10 times

<p><font color="#ff0000" size="6">KBS2</font></p>
```

Comment: share your response..

Comment: what do you mean "share my response"?

Comment: the response you get using jsoup.

Comment: k i edited my answer

Comment: -_- thanks for the help...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34723544/363573

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS selector here:

```
div.entrytext p:has(font:containsOwn(SBS)) ~ p:not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)) ~ p):not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)))
```

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~sTCURuIFhPww_PiP1QZJE_s-WDE

#### DESCRIPTION

```
div.entrytext                            /* Select div (A) with class entrytex */
p:has(font:containsOwn(SBS))             /* Select any p (B) descendant of (A) with <font>SBS</font> */
~ p                                      /* Select all p preceded by (B)... */
:not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)) ~ p)  /* ... but exclude any p preceded by <font>KBS2</font> */
:not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)))      /* ... and exclude the p tag having <font>KBS2</font> */
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String htmlpart = ""
        + "<div class=\"entrytext\">"
        + "<p>1</p>"
        + "<p><font>SBS</font></p>"
        + "<p>3</p>"
        + "<p>4</p>"
        + "<p>5</p>"
        + "<p><font>KBS2</font></p>"
        + "<p>7</p>"
        + "</div>"
        ;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlpart);
Elements allPs = doc.select("div.entrytext p:has(font:containsOwn(SBS)) ~ p:not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)) ~ p):not(p:has(font:containsOwn(KBS2)))");

System.out.println(allPs);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Comment: Indeed a nice all CSS solution, although I personally find such complex selectors hard to comprehend. One should really explain such beasts in comments to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @luksch There is no `between` CSS selector (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457187/css-between-selector). As a last resort, we use a (hackish?) workaround described here in my post. The same approach (among other solutions) is also used with jQuery (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/481889/363573). However, find a simpler version of this recipe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723544/how-to-extract-any-nodes-between-a-node-a-and-a-node-b-with-jsoup?lq=1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put such complex logic inside any sort of selectors. I think you probably need a little algorithm for that. Here is my solution:

```
String htmlpart = ""
    + "<div class=\"entrytext\">"
    + "<p>1</p>"
    + "<p><font>SBS</font></p>"
    + "<p>3</p>"
    + "<p>4</p>"
    + "<p>5</p>"
    + "<p><font>KBS2</font></p>"
    + "<p>7</p>"
    + "</div>"
    ;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlpart);
Elements allPs = doc.select("div[class=entrytext] > p");
boolean rem = true;
for (Iterator<Element> elemIter = allPs.iterator(); elemIter.hasNext();){
    Element p = elemIter.next();            
    if (!p.select("font:matchesOwn(^SBS)").isEmpty() || !p.select("font:matchesOwn(^KBS2)").isEmpty()){
        rem = !rem;
        elemIter.remove(); //remove the font elements in question
    }
    else if (rem){
        elemIter.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(allPs);
```

This will result in the following output.

```
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Comment: Please check this alternative with a CSS selector only: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787179/363573