# How to extract any nodes between a node A and a node B with Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to extract data from a site to construct a database.

I want to extract the data from "h2#1" to the line before "h2#2",
and put it into Element, so that I can handle the data easier.

The data shown in the picture is within a div where id="left"

The page I am trying to extract data:
http://koryaku.fullbokko.drecom.jp/quests/sp/eiketsu_sinka_no_hihou/netureinokishi/#1
[image]

Comment: Please provide a working example of what you have tried, so that people can help you debug it instead of waiting for others to write it for you.

Comment: Can you post the link to your post or paste the html code in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS selector:

```
h2#1 ~ *:not(h2#2 ~ *):not(h2#2)
```

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~T29QSXFbJqwJx2a_If4qUeD1cnU

#### DESCRIPTION

```
h2#1 ~ *       /* Select any node preceded by h2#1 ... */
:not(h2#2 ~ *) /* ... and not preceded by h2#2 ... */
:not(h2#2)     /* ... and exclude h2#2 itself ! */
```

**Tested on Jsoup 1.8.3**

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I am trying to do